# Normalizing a string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am pretty new at coding so I would appreciate any advice or suggestion.

I have a script which normalizes the header, however, it ignores the numbers at the beginning and I have run into an issue, where I have multiple columns with the same header title so I have added a number in front to differentiate them. For example "1.Project #"

The purpose of the script is to do a mail merge. I was wondering if there is a way to modify it so that it does not ignore the number in front? Please see script below:

```html
// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could look at RegEx.

Comment: Thanks, @AnthonyHorne! I tried the snippet below from a tutorial I found here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge but it didn't work.

`code // template: string containing markers, for instance ${"Column name"}
// data: JavaScript object with values to that will replace markers. For instance
// data.columnName will replace marker ${"Column name"}
function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
  var email = template;
// Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance ${"Column name"}
  var templateVars = template.match(/\$\{\"[^\"]+\"\}/g);`

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the 3 lines `    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) { continue; // first character must be a letter
    }`  Which make up the third if section of your current code.

Comment: Personally, I would have been inclined to split the string on spaces and deal  with each word in an array one at a time. Then join them back together as a camel code string.   By the way, what's the point of doing this?

Comment: @Cooper I have a Google Form which collects additional time-off requests and the client would like for employees to submit hours for the entire week all at once rather than each day as a separate submission. I am trying to create a mail merge which would send an email to the manager with the hours and an approve/deny link for them to approve directly in the email sent. I found an open source script for vacations which I am trying to modify to accommodate the multiple fields which share similar headings. Ideally, using tags as these ${"Column name"} would make it easier to reference columns.